# How do I use a html file to link to another html file?

Tags: html

homepage_template.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>




    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="keywords" content="HTML, CSS">
    <meta name="description" content="My programing resume in the form of a django project built from scrarch">
    
     

    <title>Resume Homepage</title>


</head>


<body>
   <h1>Welcome To My Django Resume Webpage !&copy;</h1>

   <img src="main_photo.jpg" alt="Image Unable To Be Displayed">
   <p  </p>

   <h2>Coding Projects </h2>

   <a href="homepage_photos/test.html"> text!</a>


</body>


</html>
```

The above html file is located in a folder named templates.

In templates I have another folder named homepage_photos.

In homepage_photos I have a html file called test.html

Consider when I'm viewing homepage_template.html (on my website) that my URL looks
like this - "mywebsite"

Whenever the link is clicked the URL would go to mywebsite/homepage_photos/test.html instead of just going
to the file itself

Side note: I'm using Django

Comment: Your question is not clear at all. What, specifically, are you trying to do, and what difficulty are you having in doing it? This has nothing to do with either Django or Python...

Comment: I want to be able to click the link in my anchor tag and go to a new html file. Instead what happens is what ever is in that href "" it just adds on to the url.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to make it clearer what URL you are on now, and what URL you want to be on when you click the link, and why you don't just enter that URL into the `href` attribute.

Comment: So you want to load a new page at a different location but keep the same URL as the original?

Comment: Consider when I'm viewing homepage_template.html (on my website) that my URL looks like this - "mywebsite"

Whenever the link is clicked the URL would go to mywebsite/homepage_photos/test.html instead of just going to the file itself

Comment: I suppose I could just add the direct link like 'projects' then create a url path for that url. But i feel like this is bad practice or am I wrong

Comment: you are repeating yourself.  What do you mean by go to the file itself....  What exactly do you want to happen when you click on the link

Comment: are you looking to see the files in the folder?

Comment: Nevermind sorry for being so confusing lol. I think I got it figured out thanks for trying to help anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Your pathways may be incorrect based on the way that your files are organized. If you simply name the file (ex. `homepage_photos/test.html`) then it will only work if `homepage_photos` is in the same folder as this html file. In order to go back a folder you can lead the pathway with `../` (ex. `../homepage_photos/test.html` will go back one folder before looking for `homepage_photos`. Lastly you can also lead with `/` in order to start in the original folder (where your `index` or the like is likely contained) (note that leading with `/` does not work well when using Github Pages to host)

Answer (score 0):

You have done one mistake in href arribute. You are saying that all your files are in one folder and the desired path is in another folder. So you should use / before describing the path like this:

```
<a href="/homepage_photos/test.html"> text!</a>
```